# Classes and interfaces in Angular 9

Tags: angular, oop

I am pretty new to Angular and how to use oop in this context. I have used a user interface when register a new user.

```
 export interface User {
 firstName: string;
 lastName: string;
 email: string;
 password: string;
 }
```

When I edit that user there needs more fields (role, id etc).

```
export interface User {
_id: string;
role: string;
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
email: string;
password: string;
date: string;
```

}

Shall I use two interfaces - one for registering and one for editing or should I use a class with required fields and non-required? What is best practice here? Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create interface with optional and not-optional properties like below:

```
   export interface User {
    id: number;
    name?: string; // optional parameter
  }
```

It will be better approach in your case

Comment: Thank you! That will do it!!